# SSRS - Report Builder - Data in one column divided into 2 columns

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix, reportbuilder, datacolumn

I am creating a report, and the data that i have is coming down in one column.  I have been asked to divide the data into 2 columns to save space in the report. Below is the example of the data that i have:

| Illnesses |
| --- |
| Allergies |
| Cancer |
| High Cholesterol |
| Hypertension |
| Other: Testing |

I need it to be like:

| Illnesses | Illnesses |
| --- | --- |
| Allergies | Cancer |
| High Cholesterol | Hypertension |
| Other: Testing |  |

This is the expression i found and used the data box in the report:

`=iif(RunningValue(Fields!Illness.Value, CountDistinct, "MajorIllnesses") Mod 2 = 0, True, False)`

`=iif(RunningValue(Fields!Illness.Value, CountDistinct, "MajorIllnesses") Mod 2 = 1, True, False)`

So i am getting data into 2 columns, but it is just giving me:

| Illnesses | Illnesses |
| --- | --- |
| True | False |
| False | True |
| True |  |

Comment: Your table is displaying a boolean because that is what you are returning from your expression. It should be `=IIF(condition, result-if-true, result-if-false)` where the results will generally be a field name. Try the solution in the link above.

Comment: @ChrisLatta the solution in the link worked for me.  thanks

Comment: Only this worked for me, placing here for future reference.  The Report > Columns property  and hacks were a no go.
Using Power BI Report Builder (not SSRS, not PBI Desktop :)
[08-Horizontal Table Report][1]


  [1]: https://sqlserverbi.blog/08-horizontal-table-report/